# How do I get `language-json` working with prism-js

Tags: prismjs

I have some json that I want to highlight whenever the textarea field is changed.

Using `language-json` I don't get any nice coloring, using `language-js` I do. Isn't json supported?

Comment: according to https://prismjs.com/#supported-languages it is supported

Comment: Strange, the coloring was really blend compared to when I switched to `language-js`.

Answer (score 12):

You have to import the component as well. I'm not sure if this is "best practice" but it works for me in Angular.

```
import * as Prism from 'prismjs';
import 'prismjs/components/prism-json'; // need this
```

Without the second line, JSON syntax isn't highligted at all.

Answer (score 0):

When using cdn and in-HTML scripts, below is an example of working `json` syntax highlighting.

The *Autoloader* plugin is used - it automatically loads languages when needed. "Tomorrow night" theme is used here.

*[(prism v.1.29.0; pick the latest version here)](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prism)*

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
        <!--  loaded from: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/prism/1.29.0  -->
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/themes/prism-tomorrow.min.css" integrity="sha512-vswe+cgvic/XBoF1OcM/TeJ2FW0OofqAVdCZiEYkd6dwGXthvkSFWOoGGJgS2CW70VK5dQM5Oh+7ne47s74VTg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-7Z9J3l1+EYfeaPKcGXu3MS/7T+w19WtKQY/n+xzmw4hZhJ9tyYmcUS+4QqAlzhicE5LAfMQSF3iFTK9bQdTxXg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.29.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js" integrity="sha512-SkmBfuA2hqjzEVpmnMt/LINrjop3GKWqsuLSSB3e7iBmYK7JuWw4ldmmxwD9mdm2IRTTi0OxSAfEGvgEi0i2Kw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
                const json = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
    
                const container = document.createElement('div');
                const pre = document.createElement('pre');
                const code = document.createElement('code');
                code.className = 'language-json';
                code.textContent = JSON.stringify(json, null, 4);
    
                pre.appendChild(code);
                container.appendChild(pre);
    
                document.body.appendChild(container);
                Prism.highlightAll();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Result:**

[image: JSON syntax highlighting]